# Unity 3D - Particles suddenly becoming transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

I'm developing a 3D game using Unity3D 4.5.2 (free version, not Pro).

I have used a default Particle System to make a Waterfall. I have placed the Waterfall particle system in the scene in such a way that there is a 2D Sprite of a Mountain behind it.

This is to give an impression to the user that the Waterfall is 'falling' out from the Mountain.

However, after 10 seconds on simulating this waterfall particle system, the particles suddenly become transparent, enabling the user to view the Mountain behind it...have provided screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

So I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out here, as I've looked at a lot of solutions & fiddled around with all the parameters of the particle system in Inspector but to no avail...

Comment: We need more details about it. Can you screen grab particle system component in inspector? posting video might help also

Answer (score 1):

To give you the correct answer for this question, I need see your particle system parameters. But I think something is wrong with "Max Particles" amount or "Color over lifetime". Also check "Start Lifetime", maybe it is too much.